# trying to return items data from invoice

Tags: laravel

i need to manage invoice items.
here is my code below
in my model i've got this

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(invoice_product::class);
}
```

in the invoice_product model

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsTo(prodStock::class);
}
```

and my controller below is

```
public function show(invoice $invoice, $id)
{
    $invoice = Invoice::with('items.products')->findOrFail($id);

    return view('pages.editInvoice', compact('invoice'));
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with item data?

Comment: i want to view fiirst then edit on dropdown select if possible

Comment: Do you want to display this array as a list in view?

Comment: yes, i want to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since we are passing variables using compact in the controller, all we have to do is get the view
**controller**

```
public function show(invoice $invoice, $id)
{
$invoice = Invoice::with('items.products')->findOrFail($id);

return view('pages.editInvoice', compact('invoice'));
}
```

**view**

```
<select>
@foreach($invoice as $in)
  <option value="{{ $in->ColumnName }}">{{ $in->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

If you do like this, you will be able to select in the drop down select